# Mesh clipping through itself when posing

Tags: mesh, armature

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JjNyxda5UV30k6mR2PuABnHGE-zigrHs/view?usp=sharing
This is the link to the blend file, I think I figured out most of my issues when working with it but when I pose the mesh with its aramature the arm clips through the clothes and I don't know if I am did something wrong or if thats normal?

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the blendfile over blendexchange, https://blend-exchange.com/ , that way it will not get lost and is safer to access for everybody. On the note of the question, I would take a look at weight painting

Comment: I was looking at the weight paint but I still don't know what I am doing wrong